# What is the Independence Day that Inoue Marina has been tweeting about lately?

Tags: japanese-language, voice-acting

Lately Inoue Marina has been tweeting about Independence Day. For example 2018-02-05 she tweeted,

> 独立記念日全公演全て終了！
>   今回は女子2人が交互にストーリーテラーとなっていく構成でかなりの集中力を要しましたが大変にやり甲斐のあるものでした。回を追う毎にキャスト皆の絆が深まって行って、とても素敵な空気感の中で幕を降ろす事が出来ました。
>   来て下さった皆様、有難うございました！ https://t.co/CMlzcoSb7B

2018-02-04 she tweeted

> 独立記念日1回目終わりました〜！
>   あと2回！集中していきます！

and

> 本日は砂岡事務所プロデュースリーディング公演、「独立記念日vol.2」です！ なんか今雪降ってきてビビってます。おそらくすぐ止むと思いますが。
>   いらっしゃる皆様、お気をつけて！

2018-01-23

> 砂岡事務所プロデュースリーディング公演『独立記念日』Vol.2の稽古が行われました。
>   石川由依ちゃんと井上ってそれどこの進…というのは冗談として一緒に出演するのが由依ちゃんなのでめっちゃリラックスして臨んでおります。
>   男性キャストの代永ウィング、福井貴一さんも滅茶滅茶素敵です！ https://t.co/Z1W6hVYdak

What is this "Independence Day" thing is about? Is it a Live movie? Does this means that she will become an drama actress now?

Comment: could you post the English translation for us peasant

Comment: @Darjeeling Google translate it. Or maybe summon krazer for help. I used Google translate myself (it's too advanced for me T.T), which might be why I don't understand her tweet. What I'm sure is that 独立記念日 means Independence day and when googled it would result into US Independence Day.

Comment: @Aki actually I ask this question because it might lead us to an answer for my other question, "What does Seiyuu do after they are no longer at the peak of their game?"

Comment: well without fully understand what she tweeted it sounds like you're asking for English translation of her tweet, which is off topic..

Comment: but well, @AkiTanaka seems to understand what you mean so I'm not gonna vtc this

Comment: Found the link of the [official website](http://sunaoka.com/stage/idd02/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

独立記念日 (*Dokuritsu Kinenbi*, Independence Anniversary*) is a live reading event produced by 砂岡事務所プロデュース (Sunaoka Creative Artist Agency, [official website (Japanese)](http://sunaoka.com/)).

A short introduction on "what is a live reading?", it's a live staged reading event where voice actors and actresses read a story script live in front of audiences, or to put it simply, *live audio drama*. [Live Read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_Read) is one of such internationally-acclaimed events that can be found on Wikipedia.

Back to *Dokuritsu Kinenbi*, it's a 2-day live reading event which took places on Saturday and Sunday. There were 5 scripts: 2 scripts on the first day and 3 scripts on the second day. Each script consisted of 4 casts and took around 75~80 minutes without breaks. As it could be inferred from the tweet, it has been produced 2 times (as of Feb 2018):

- *Dokuritsu Kinenbi*: 12-13 Aug 2017 ([official site (Japanese)](http://sunaoka.com/stage/idd/))
- *Dokuritsu Kinenbi vol.2*: 3-4 Feb 2018 ([official site (Japanese)](http://sunaoka.com/stage/idd02/))

This is how the stage for *vol.2* looks like

[image: stage for vol.2]

<sup>From [*Sunaoka Jimusho*'s official Twitter account](https://twitter.com/sunaokaoffice02/status/959956414784356352)</sup>

---

<sup>*The English name is taken from these Facebook posts: [Ishikawa Kaito](https://www.facebook.com/kaijinkun/photos/a.1494377364136083.1073741827.1481137862126700/1917590275148121/?type=3&theater) and [Hanae Natsuki](https://www.facebook.com/hanaecchi0626/photos/a.1402693760031388.1073741828.1402484613385636/1732971917003569/?type=3&theater)</sup>

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what else to be included. Let me know and I'll try (or give up) improving this.

Comment: If you can improve this, please do. But anyway +1 and I accept this as answer. It is pretty clear for me once you said live audio drama. And looking at the pic Inoue Marina tweeted, I though she's doing stage acting. Geez.